# How to save browsing history of UIwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am developing an app where there is a requirement under which there is show wikipedia link in Web

view.and also there is showing history of pages open via web view in a table view.I have find it on goo

gle but can't find any solution.How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you want to back and forward functionality need or just history need?

Comment: I also want back functionality along with history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code for the backward and forward into UIWebViewController

```
 - (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
      [webView goBack];
    }

    - (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {
      [webView goForward];
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't address keeping track of the history. See the answer by Paresh below.

Answer (score 5):

`UIWebView` has `goBack` and `goForward` method. Refer [here].(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Don't forget to add `UIWebViewDelegate` in .h and its object `delegate` to `self`.

Also can store `url` in `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *documentURL = request.mainDocumentURL;

    if(![history containsObject:documentURL.absoluteString]){
        [arrBrowseHistory addObject:documentURL.absoluteString];
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, the currently selected answer only answers half of the question.

Comment: This doesn't deal with UIWebView's behavior of passing every sub-resource in the page through shouldStartLoadWithRequest and cluttering your history.

Comment: @jasonjwwilliams Edited the original with fix.